# Why do we require that the collection of elements in a group form a set?

Tags: group-theory

According to Wikipedia, the collection of elements in a group forms a set.  Is this true, and if it is true is there ever a case where we use something that doesn't work if they instead formed a proper class?

Comment: It makes it much harder to talk about subgroups and the like. And some versions of set theory don't have "classes," including the most commonly used version, ZFC.

Comment: It is my understanding that the [Surreal Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) are a proper class yet still satisfies the properties (*apart from being a set*) of being a field (*and therefore also the properties of being a group*).

Comment: Conway would have called such a thing a Group rather than a group.

Comment: Pretty similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83426/87023

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, a group is defined as a set with an operation on that set.
2. I believe that the reason groups must operate on sets rather than on some exotic collection is simply convenience. Mathematicians are used to working with sets, and we have lots of familiar notation and technology (e.g. subsets, relations, and functions) that are defined only on sets.